# Cant run java Programm on startup (Raspbian)

Tags: linux, shell-script, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have 2 Java programs (.jar) on my raspberry pi and they should be executed on startup.

I accomplished this by writing a sh script, that executes the both programs (started from console both are working)
Both of this script should be executed by the rc.local at the startup of the raspberry pie.

The problem I have is, that only my first Programm is starting and the second doesn't.
I can tell that because the first rogramm starts logging, but the second one doesn't even create the log file.
Therefore, I am completely new to Linux I got no clue if I am having a wrong approach or just some minor mistake.

Path to the jar's: /home/pi/Programms/Projectfolder/jar

rc.local:

```
cd /init.d
sh StartPantaBot.sh
sh StartHandballTippspiel.sh
```

These are the lines executing the 2 sh scripts wich are located within /etc/init.d

StartPantaBot.sh:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/StartPantaBot.sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          StartPantaBot.sh
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Simple script to start the Pantabot at boot
# Description:       A simple script
### END INIT INFO

chmod -R 777 /home/pi/Programms/PantaBot
java -jar /home/pi/Programms/PantaBot/PantaBot.jar >/var/log/logPantaBot.txt
```

The other one is looking similar

Comment: I think the problem is in `rc.local` at first line `cd /init.d`, you should use `cd /etc/init.d`. Btw, are you sure you are not using `systemd`?

Comment: i have both scripts for the start in the init.d folder and the first one gets executed and starts so i dont think that this is the problem, even tho the `rc.local` is within `/etc`

idk about system.d, never heard about this

Comment: Oh! yes. I'm thinking now what should be the problem. Try running your scripts in background using `&` at the end: `sh StartPantaBot.sh&` `sh StartHandballTippspiel.sh&`.

Comment: this worked thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the run command to see if this works
, Try running a Java application with this command

```bash
nohup java -jar /home/pi/Programms/PantaBot/PantaBot.jar  > /var/log/logPantaBot.txt 2>&1 &
```